# Expose Lightning App Builder page publicly using Lightning out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I am trying to find a solution that allows me to expose a lightning page that I build using lightning app builder to an unauthenticated website via lightning out.

I know that I can use 'ltng:allowGuestAccess' to allow unauthenticated access if I compose my page to an app in code.

However, my requirement is that I need to be able to drag and drop components on a page publicly accessible.

The best solution I can think of is to buy one community license and build the page using community builder and then expose this page publicly.

If anyone has any other ideas I would much appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.

As per my experience, on your community page, assuming it is Napili, you can drag and drop the components. Then you can make this page public so every one can have access.

I doubt if you can use Lightning Out to compose a specific page but only components.

> However, my requirement is that I need to be able to drag and drop components on a page publicly accessible.

This part confuses me, if you use Lightning Out to expose component to public, why do you need to drag and drop it to the page?